# how to take average and normalize of xml data

Tags: xml, xslt

Could you please help me in developing a xsl code that could do the following activities sequentially:
1. take average of two elements
2. normalize the average value across records.

Where I am stumped in the development of xsl is the reuse of a newly added for the next element.
Any help would be appreciated

Example:
In the sample input file below for each record
1. avg = (c + d)/2
    - avg = (c+d)/2 = (12+12)/2 = 12, (8+12)/2=10 ....
2. avg_nom = avg/min(avg)
    - avg_nom = avg/min(avg) = 12/min(12,10,15,27)=1.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
<Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>10</b>
    <c>12</c>
    <d>12</d>
</Results>
<Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>8</b>
    <c>8</c>
    <d>12</d>
</Results>
<Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>6</b>
    <c>10</c>
    <d>20</d>
</Results>
<Results>
    <a>yes</a>
    <b>23</b>
    <c>20</c>
    <d>34</d>
</Results>
 </top>
```

The expected result should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
<Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>10</b>
    <avg>12</avg>
    <avg_nom>1.2</avg_nom>
    <c>12</c>
    <d>12</d>
</Results>
<Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>8</b>
    <avg>10</avg>
    <avg_nom>1</avg_nom>
    <c>8</c>
    <d>12</d>
</Results>
<Results>
    <a>no</a>
    <b>6</b>
    <avg>15</avg>
    <avg_nom>1.5</avg_nom>
    <c>10</c>
    <d>20</d>
</Results>
<Results>
    <a>yes</a>
    <b>23</b>
    <avg>27</avg>
    <avg_nom>2.7</avg_nom>
    <c>20</c>
    <d>34</d>
</Results>
</top>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version do you use? If you want to avoid computing values several times you really need to do a two step transformation which is easy in XSLT 2.0 (with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9) but requires the use of an extension function like `exsl:node-set` in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I am currently using XSLT 1.0. But I am looking to make minimize the number of steps, as I have already divided my process into two modules. 1. normalization of values for sorting and 2. filtering records toget the final output. On the other side, I want to keep it simple allowing it to be run on multiple platforms(Linux & Win). As you may have guessed, I am new to this language and this development is my first attempt to process xml database using xslt. Your help/advice is highly appriciated.

Comment: I have edited the answer below to add an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet. Needs `exsl:node-set` or similar.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="step1-result">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="top" mode="step1"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c" mode="step1">
  <avg><xsl:value-of select="(. + ../d) div 2"/></avg>
  <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="min-avg" select="min($step1-result/top/Results/avg)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1-result/top/*">
      <xsl:with-param name="min-avg" tunnel="yes" select="$min-avg"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="avg">
  <xsl:param name="min-avg" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:next-match/>
  <avg_nom><xsl:value-of select=". div $min-avg"/></avg_nom>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is an XSLT 1.0 version of above stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="step1-result-fragment">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="top" mode="step1"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="step1-result" select="exsl:node-set($step1-result-fragment)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="step1" name="step1-identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="step1"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c" mode="step1">
  <avg><xsl:value-of select="(. + ../d) div 2"/></avg>
  <xsl:call-template name="step1-identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="min-avg">
      <xsl:for-each select="$step1-result/top/Results/avg">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1-result/top/Results">
      <xsl:with-param name="min-avg" select="$min-avg"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Results">
  <xsl:param name="min-avg"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
      <xsl:with-param name="min-avg" select="$min-avg"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="avg">
  <xsl:param name="min-avg"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <avg_nom><xsl:value-of select=". div $min-avg"/></avg_nom>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin, thanks for your effort but I am having trouble runnning this code in my linux environment, Could help me in writing this code in XSLT 1.0. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? libxslt/xsltproc should support `exsl:node-set`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am trying adapt the code to a different data set which has more elements in the tree, but I am stumped with your code, could you give me any tips. Sample xml has elements <top> <level1> <Results> ... The output produced with this code only has <top> <Results>.... I basically lose <level1> data.

Comment: Well try to adapt the code to the new input. If you can't work out yourself how to achieve that, then post a new question detailing the new input structure, the wanted result, and your attempts to adapt the code.