# Understanding "exsl:node-set" for Multiple operations on input xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to understand the concept of "exsl:node-set" and its use, that enables the processing of processed/generated elements in a XML. Could anyone help

I started with the developing a XSL code that could do the following activities sequentially:

1. take average of two elements
2. normalize the average value across records.

Example:
 In the sample input file below for each record

1. avg = (c + d)/2

   - avg = (c+d)/2 = (12+12)/2 = 12, (8+12)/2=10 ....
2. avg_nom = avg/min(avg)

   - avg_nom = avg/min(avg) = 12/min(12,10,15,27)=1.2

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <Level1>
        <Results>
            <a>no</a>
            <b>10</b>
            <b_nom>1.66</b_nom>
            <c>12</c>
            <d>9</d>
        </Results>
    </Level1>
    <Level1>
         <Results>
             <a>no</a>
             <b>8</b>
             <b_nom>1.33</b_nom>
             <c>50</c>
             <d>12</d>
         </Results>
    <Level1>
    </Level1>
         <Results>
             <a>no</a>
             <b>6</b>
             <b_nom>1</b_nom>
             <c>55</c>
             <d>56</d>
         </Results>
    <Level1>
    </Level1>
         <Results>
             <a>yes</a>
             <b>23</b>
             <b_nom>1</b_nom>
             <c>32</c>
             <d>34</d>
         </Results>
    </Level1>
</top>
```

Code: This code was [provided as a response to earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466087/how-to-take-average-and-normalize-of-xml-data) where the sample XML had only two levels in the tree  ie. `<top><Results>`

For which this works perfectly fine, but for the above XML input, I lose data of `<Level1>`. I do not understand the code and make the necessary corrections.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="step1-result-fragment">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="top" mode="step1"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="step1-result" select="exsl:node-set($step1-result-fragment)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="step1" name="step1-identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="step1"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c" mode="step1">
  <avg><xsl:value-of select="(. + ../d) div 2"/></avg>
  <xsl:call-template name="step1-identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="min-avg">
      <xsl:for-each select="$step1-result/top//Results/avg">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1-result/top//Results">
      <xsl:with-param name="min-avg" select="$min-avg"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Results">
  <xsl:param name="min-avg"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
      <xsl:with-param name="min-avg" select="$min-avg"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="avg">
  <xsl:param name="min-avg"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>    
  <avg_nom><xsl:value-of select=". div $min-avg"/></avg_nom>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I need is not only the correction to the above code to get the correct output but also to understand the code further. For this I would like to add a additional step to the above example

3. Final=(b_nom+avg_nom)/2

Hence the final output should look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<top>
    <Level1>
      <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <b_nom>1.66</b_nom>
        <avg>10.5</avg>
        <avg_nom>1</avg_nom>
        <final>5.5</final>
        <c>12</c>
        <d>9</d>
      </Results>
    </Level1>
    <Level1>
      <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>8</b>
        <b_nom>1.33</b_nom>
        <avg>31</avg>
        <avg_nom>2.95238095238095</avg_nom>
        <final>2.14</final>
        <c>50</c>
        <d>12</d>
      </Results>
    </Level1>
    <Level1>
      <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>6</b>
        <b_nom>1</b_nom>
        <avg>55.5</avg>
        <avg_nom>5.28571428571429</avg_nom>
        <final>3.14</final>
        <c>55</c>
        <d>56</d>
      </Results>
    </Level1>
    <Level1>
      <Results>
        <a>yes</a>
        <b>23</b>
        <b_nom>1</b_nom>
        <avg>33</avg>
        <avg_nom>3.14285714285714</avg_nom>
        <final>2.07</final>
        <c>32</c>
        <d>34</d>
      </Results>
    </Level1>
</top>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, you can create a variable whose value is a tree:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <root>
    <xsl:call-template name="do-something"/>
  </root>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then you can use the full power of XSLT to process this tree

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$temp" mode="postprocess"/>
```

This allows a stylesheet to operate in several phases: you can create an intermediate result, and then postprocess it: you can perform the transformation in as many phases as you like.

In XSLT 1.0, as a result of a bad design mistake late in the development of the spec, this was not permitted. The restriction is enforced by making `$temp` be a "result tree fragment" and disallowing operations such as xsl:apply-templates on result tree fragments.

The mistake was realised very soon after XSLT 1.0 came out, and processor vendors got around it, without introducing a non-conformance with the spec, by introducing the extension function exslt:node-set(). This allows you to write

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($temp)" mode="postprocess"/>
```

Conceptually, exslt:node-set() converts a result tree fragment (which xsl:apply-templates isn't allowed to process) into a singleton node set (which it is). Probably in most implementations it's pretty well a no-op.

I hope this helps you to understand what your stylesheet is doing.